# Calendar extender is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement to show edit panel as second row of a datagrid upon addnew link click. for this I have taken a div which has set display:none. I am able to show as second row upon addnew link click. now the actual problem starts.

this div got a text box which is tied to calendar extender  to behave as a claendar upon textbox click. but calendar is not showing up when the html of invisible div is inserted as second row of grid. please let me know if anyone need code for better understanding the problem. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your gridview put a templatedfield instead of a div. make that templated field hold a textbox and calender extender.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="textbox1" runat="server">
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

but If you want it when your inserting you should put

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="textbox1" runat="server">
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="textbox1" runat="server">
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: i can't change grid at this stage of my project as this is designed to work as i described above. is there any possibility to make calendar extender work if it is taken from a div which has set display:none.

Comment: Posting your code would help me out, I don't know what you grid looks like currently.

Comment: thanks for your help. I know above said one  but in my case i have to take from div which has set to display none. I did resolve by grabbing the behavior id of the calendar and calling show method and changing top and left positions of the calendar to make it appear beneath the target control. thanks very much your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %> 

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxControlToolkit" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head runat="server"> 
    <title></title> 
    <script src="jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function AddCalendars() 
        { 

            //The last parameter should be the TargetControl's id. If you use "TextBox1", the TextBox1 would be associated. 
            var elem = $(".deneme"); 

            for (var a = 0; a < elem.length; a++) 
             { 
                 if ($find("CalendarExtender"  + elem[a].id)) 
                 { 
                   $find("CalendarExtender" + elem[a].id).dispose(); 
                 } 
            } 
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) 
            { 
                $create(AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarBehavior, { "id": "CalendarExtender" + elem[i].id  }, null, null, elem[i]); 
            } 

        } 
    </script> 

</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" /> 
        <%--the dummy calendar which is used to download the related script file.--%> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="dummyTextBox" runat="server" Style="display: none"></asp:TextBox> 
        <AjaxControlToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="dummyCalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
            TargetControlID="dummyTextBox"> 
        </AjaxControlToolkit:CalendarExtender> 
        <%--the dummy calendar which is used to download the related script file.--%> 
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="AddCalendars();return false" runat="server" 
            Text="CreateCalendarFromClient" /><br /> 
        input:<input id="deneme1" type="text" class="deneme" /><br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        <br /> 
        TextBox: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="deneme2" runat="server" cssclass="deneme" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox> 
    </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```